# Reversing some words in a string

Tags: java

I need to reverse 5 or more character long words in a given string. For example: 
* Given string: My name is Michael. 
* Output: My name is leahciM.

Rest of the sentence stays the same, just those long words get reversed.

So far I came up with this:

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
    String reversedSentence = "";
    String reversedWord = "";
    for (String str : splitWords) {
        if (str.length() >= 5) {
            for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                reversedWord += (str.charAt(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

And I have reversed those words, but 
1) they are in one string, without a space
2) I dont know how to put them back into their places in string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

- write a method that reverses a string:

  ```
  private static String reverse(String s) { ... }
  ```
- then in your main method, call it when necessary:

  ```
  if (str.length() >= 5) str = reverse(str);
  ```
- you then need to put the words back together, presumably into the `reversedSentence` string:

  ```
  reversedSentence += str + " "; //you will have an extra space at the end
  ```

Side notes:

- using a `StringBuilder` may prove more efficient than string concatenation for longer sentences.
- you could put all the words back into a `List<String>` within the loop and call `reversedSentence = String.join(" ", list)` after the loop
- reversing a string can be done in one line - you should find numerous related Q&As on stackoverflow.

Comment: Is there a way to remove that space at the end? I really like your method without suing StringBuilder (I dont think I can use additional libraries at codewars).

Comment: @doublemc *"you could put all the words back into a List<String> within the loop and call reversedSentence = String.join(" ", list) after the loop"* or check the other answer using `String#trim()`

Comment: @doublemc one trick is to have a `boolean firstWord = true` and in your loop: `if (firstWord) { result = str; firstWord = false; } else { result += " " + str; }`

Comment: @assylias To be honest I just checked and if I have a long first word (eg. Michael is my name) it doesnt reverse that. Where exactly do I put that if? Got that as of now: https://gist.github.com/doublemc/04592ef8d751d7e3928cb511ace248c3

Comment: @assylias Alright, just used method trim() and it works perfectly fine!

Comment: @doublemc - to remove spaces, put the words into an array as you decide to reverse them or not.  Then join the array with spaces, then put the period at the end (if needed)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `StringBuilder`

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String str : splitWords) {
       if (str.length() < 5) {
           builder.append(str);
       else
           builder.append(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());

       builder.append(" ");
    }

    return builder.toString().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use anything else you almost had it, just check your "for" loops and remember to add the unreversed string.

```
public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
    String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
    String reversedSentence = "";
    String reversedWord;
    for (String str : splitWords) {
        if (str.length() >= 5) {
            reversedWord = "";
            for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                reversedWord += (str.charAt(i));
            }
            reversedSentence += " " + reversedWord;
        } else {
            reversedSentence += " " + str;
        }
    }
    return reversedSentence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `StringBuilder` to build the answer as you process the elements in `splitWords`.

You may also find the idiom of `space` with special first-time value (being "") useful.

There was also a bug in your original code.

So here is what I would do:

```
public class ReverseLongWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String testInput = "My name is Michael";

        System.out.println(spinWords(testInput));

    }

    public static String spinWords(String sentence) {
        String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
        String reversedSentence = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String space = "";              // first time special
        String reversedWord = "";
        for (String str : splitWords) {
            if (str.length() >= 5) {
                for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    reversedWord += (str.charAt(i));    // Bug fixed
                }
                sb.append(space + reversedWord);
            } else {
                sb.append(space + str);
            }
            space = " ";                // second time and onwards
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

The output of this program is the following, as you have specified:

```
My name is leahciM
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the reverse method as some people suggest would be the easiest way, here I share my implementation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(concatenatePhrase("My name is Michael"));
    System.out.println(concatenatePhrase("Some randoms words with differents sizes and random words"));
}

private static String concatenatePhrase(String phrase) {
    StringBuilder completePhrase = new StringBuilder();
    String[] phrases = phrase.split(" ");
    for (String word : phrases) {
        if (word.length() >= 5) {
            completePhrase.append(reverseWord(word).append(" "));
        } else {
            completePhrase.append(word).append(" ");
        }
    }
    return completePhrase.toString().trim();
}

private static StringBuilder reverseWord(String wordPassed) {
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(wordPassed);
    return word.reverse();
}
```